# Can Bootstrap (4) be integrated along with Angular Material (2)?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-material2

I'd like to use Angular Material 2 library, because of its (growing list of) components. But i'm used to bootstrap and it's goodies like responsive utilities and lightweight UI for typical things. By Bootstrap I mostly mean its CSS part, I almost never need its JS functionality.

For example in Material lilbrary there is practically zero styling for list group, while Bootstrap gives that with its css.

I remember reading that combining them is not a good idea, mainly because their global app-wide styles will collide. I can't find that source and I'm curios - is that true with current versions? If so, exactly what is conflicting and how can it be worked around?

Comment: If you want to use Angular with Bootstrap elements, things like https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ exist

Answer (score 17):

Since Bootstrap is modular, one alternative approach could be using Angular Material and then just picking from Bootstrap only the parts that you really need.

---

**Note**: whatever you're going to import, you should install bootstrap first:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

And import the required sass file inside your global `style.scss`:

```
 // Imports functions, variables, and mixins that are needed by other Bootstrap files
 @import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
 @import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
 @import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

---

For example, you might want to use [Bootstrap Reboot](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/reboot/) in order to make all browsers render the elements more consistently and following the web standards.

Then you only need to import:

```
// Import Roboot
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
```

You probably want to make use of the [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) as well, in such case you can further add:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid"; // add the grid
```

So you would be able to use it in your html templates:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may also want to use the [Bootstrap Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/), in such case add also:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities"; // add css utilities
```

---

My answer is based on what's explained here in details: https://www.amadousall.com/the-good-parts-of-bootstrap-4-you-are-missing-in-your-angular-material-projects/

Comment: Actually, you might want to skip Reboot or add your own MD-compatible "fixes" above it. For example, I found that Reboot collides with MD buttons by adding borders when button is in focused state, while clean MD doesn't have borders.

Comment: @JustAMartin I am having that issue I tried to import only grid from bootstrap because is what I need, and gets me some undefined variables when I do the import

Answer (score 9):

[Angular Material 2](https://github.com/angular/components) is a new library still in active development so you should not expect many fancy `nice to have` features in that, yet, but on the long run you will have a lots of benefits using `Material 2` in you angular app. Here is some overview:

## Component Development Kit

In the last releases `Material 2` team introduced `@angular/cdk` which is a core for `Material 2` and also gives developers a great ground to write their own thirdparty components. There is no much docs on `@angular/cdk` yet, but you can track that issue https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2789 to keep updated on that matter.

## Responsive goddies

There is no builtin functionality in `Material 2` that gives you responsive goddies. For that matter you have to use [@angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) thing is completely separate from `Material 2` -  basically it is a nice abstraction on top of [Flexbox CSS](https://caniuse.com/#search=Flexbox). Using that you do not have to write whole bunch of responsive css mediaQueries yourself.

## Browsers support

`Material 2`:  IE11+
`Bootstrap 4` IE10+
`Bootstrap 3` IE8+

## Bootstrap + Material ?

It is up to you if you want to combine both Frameworks in your app. If you do that check the bundle size to make sure it is not bloated.

Comment: If you throw in everything from both Material and Bootstrap, then yes, you will have a huge load. But with both you only take what you need anyways, thus keeping the actual bundle small. Bootstrap utility classes e.g. are quite nice to work with and don't collide with Material in any way.

Comment: @seBaka28 yeah you right, I will update the answer accordingly with your comment

Answer (score 5):

While Kuncevic's answer is right, I think we should also add the following:

- Angular Material is implicitly upgrading/downgrading DOM elements
  while Bootstrap is not. That means that in Bootstrap, you get what
  you see, while in Angular Material, some elements are automatically
  rendered. So, I can't really see how you can combine the two, even if
  you want to. Adding, Angular's [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) in the mix, things 
  get even messier.
- The only part where I see room for cooperation is in the grid. You
  could use Bootstrap for the grid and Angular Material for the rest, but with Angular Flex
  Layout (as Kunsevic already mentioned) you don't really need to.
  There is a small learning curve there, but it is worth it, if you use
  Angular.
- Bootstrap's CSS does conflict with Angular Material's CSS. When used
  together I have noticed that certain elements like icons inside
  floating buttons are not centered correctly, etc. This shouldn't be a
  difficult fix, but why bother when you can use Angular Flex?

Hope that helps.

Comment: The only problem with Angular Flex Layout is it is still in beta and doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

Comment: This was written a while ago. Indeed, Angular Flex Layout looks abandoned. Since then, I have been using Bootstrap, just the grid, for layouts (option 2 in my answer).

Answer (score 4):

In 2019 Angular conference they explained is it ok or not combining bootstrap and angular material.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLj1qw82oAo&feature=youtu.be