# Angular Material 2 with Bootstrap 4 Grid

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular-material2

I am using Angular 4 and have installed Angular Material 2 as I like how the components look.

So now I have all the components and want to create a layout.

I know there's Angular Flex-layout for it but to be honest I don't know Flex that well so I was thinking on using Bootstrap's 4 Grid for sorting out the layouts.

Is there any reason why I should not use Bootstrap's grid with Angular Material2 ?

Comment: You may find some useful information in the last part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45498121/5556177)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no point to use `bootstrap grid` with `angular material2` at all.

> I don't know Flex that well so I was thinking on using Bootstrap's 4
>   Grid for sorting out the layouts.

I do not think you are quite right on that as in order to use `flex-layout` you do not have to be a `flexbox css` expert at all.

`Flex-layout` is just an abstraction API on top of `flexbox css` it is very simple to master. Just have a look in to live samples https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/ and also checkout this ngair episode https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TewrxMo_QAs to get some interesting insides on `flex-layout` from its creator Troy Burleson

Comment: Yes - no reason to import all of Bootstrap just to use its antiquated grid system! To me, even using plain css flexbox is easier than using bootstrap's grid.