# How to 'prevent' bootstrap from overriding the existing styles in the application

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, sass, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap in my angular-app to build a popover which looks something like [image: its image]
I am using custom fonts in my body which are defined in styles.scss file as

```
$r-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'TedNext, sans-serif'
);
$f-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Yolo, sans-serif'
);
html[realm=r] {
  @include mat-core($r-typography);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: TedNext, sans-serif ;
}

html[realm=f] {
  @include mat-core($f-typography);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Yolo, sans-serif ;
}
```

if I remove the bootstrap import in styles.scss the font looks [image: subtle black] and I also lose my styling for the popover [image: like this image]

when I import the boostrap.scss into styles.scss the text becomes bold [image: like this image]
but my default fonts are overridden by bootstrap [image: like this]

Here is the code for the button that has mat-icon

```
<button mat-icon-button matSuffix
                      popoverClass="popoverBackground"
                      ngbPopover="{{ 'PAYMENT.CREDIT_CARD.CVV_INFORMATION' | translate }}"
                      container="#checkId"
                      tabindex="-1"
                      type="button"
                      onclick="this.blur()"
                      [autoClose]="true"
                     class="cvv-info-button"
              >
                <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
              </button>
```

Any idea about how can I prevent bootstrap to override my normal fonts?

Comment: If one of the answers worked for you can you please accept it? Thanks, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

The .css rule that is the most specific is the one that get the priority.

Please make sure that your custom .css rules are more specific to your elements.

For example:

Given this html:

```
<div class="base">
   <div class="child">
      text
   </div>
</div>
```

And this .css rules:

```
.child {
   color: red
}
```

```
.base .child {
   color: black
}
```

Then more specific one is the second one, thus the text will be black colored.
You can override it by given the first rule more specific selectors:

```
.black div.child {
   color: red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, mixing the Angular Material and Bootstrap CSS will lead to a lot of pain. I would strongly recommend avoiding it.
Here is a good more in depth [discussion about mixing Angular Material and Bootstrap CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497542/can-bootstrap-4-be-integrated-along-with-angular-material-2).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers. It is really difficult to integrate bootstrap with angular material.

Since the bootstrap styles were getting applied on the body:

I had to override the bootstrap styles like this"

```
html[realm=r] {
  @include mat-core($r-typography);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: TedNext, sans-serif ;

 body{
    font-family: TedNext, sans-serif;
  }
}
```